# How to make protocol inheritance with strong constraints

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I would like to make some abstract protocol with generic types

```swift
protocol UseCase {
    associatedtype P
    associatedtype R
    func execute(params: P) async throws -> R
}
```

Then I would like to make some concrete protocol with some types

```swift
protocol TestUseCase: UseCase where P == Int, R == Int { }
```

And then use it to declare some implementation to use it on another side

```swift
class TestUseCaseImpl: TestUseCase {
    func execute(params: Int) async throws -> Int {
        // some impl
    }
}
```

When I try to use it inside of my view model I got such error:

```swift
class ViewModel {

    private let testUseCase: TestUseCase // error

    init(testUseCase: TestUseCase) { // errror
        self.testUseCase = testUseCase
    }
}
```

```
Protocol 'TestUseCase' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

To fix such problem I can declare generic `ViewModel` with some use case type like this:

```swift
class ViewModel<UseCase: TestUseCase> {

    private let testUseCase: UseCase

    init(testUseCase: UseCase) {
        self.testUseCase = testUseCase
    }
}
```

Problem around `ViewModel` - it's possible to have many use cases inside of `ViewModel`.
How to implement such idea without generic `ViewModel`?

Comment: What do you mean by **many use cases**?

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter Sometimes I need to inject few dependencies into `ViewModel`

Comment: Why not use generic then?

Comment: It's not very clear, what exactly do you want to achieve that is not achievable with your `ViewModel<UseCase: TestUseCase>`? It would be great to see an imagined code that you would like to have and that gives you the error that you want to get rid of.

Comment: @lazarevzubov code is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) so you cannot have just one of it/them. I.e. "an imagined code" is an invalid construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `any` keyword. This is only supported in Swift >= 5.7.

Note: it is very unlikely that you want a type called `ViewModel`. Nest type `Model` inside of `View` if that's what it is.

```swift
class ViewModel {
  private let testUseCase: any TestUseCase

  init(testUseCase: some TestUseCase) {
    self.testUseCase = testUseCase
  }
}
```